# Convert a list of entities to a list of view models

Tags: c#

I am very new to C# and the .NET Framework. I have a function in my `PublisherService` to retrieve a publisher by it's Id. It maps the `Publisher` to a view model that has the `Publishername` and a list of `BookAuthorsVM`.

You can see the classes here:

[Publisher ViewModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxgSu.png)

This is the method (it works fine):

[GetPublisherById Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvlkC.png)

Now I am trying to write a method that retrieves all publishers with their books. This is what i have but it is throwing a Null error:

[GetAllPublishers Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65Y9A.png)

Any suggestions how to do this? Do I need a foreach instead?

Best Regards,
Anthony

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess, you're using Entity Framework Core as your ORM.

EF Core doesn't use lazy-loading by default. When you load an entity into memory, its navigation properties will not be populated.

Your `GetPublisherById` method works, because the query is translated into SQL and executed on the server.

Your `GetAllPublishers` method *doesn't* work because you have a `.ToList()` call before the `.Select(...)` call, which forces the query to execute in-memory. Since you haven't told the query to include any of the related data, the `q.Books` collection is `null`.

You should be able to get the query to work by removing the first `.ToList()` call:

```
var _publisherData = _context.Publishers.Select(q => new PublisherWithBooksAndAuthorsVM
{
    ...
}).ToList();
```

[Loading Related Data - EF Core | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/)